# How to change the column width with ng-material-treetable?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, treetable

[image: Tree Table in StackBlitz example]
I realized that internally material `data-table` is being used. When I am using table `mat-table`. I can use CSS to do the below change, but somehow it is not working, how I could do that?

```
.mat-column-[columnname] { 
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Link with the code on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpcm2l?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd check your browsers output you would see that your column width is defined inside the following selector (see example):

**Example:**

```
td[class*=' mat-column'][_ngcontent-c9] {
    width: 10vw;
    min-width: 10vw;
    max-width: 10vw;
}
```

You should be able to add and modify this selector to your needs inside your scss file.

```
td[class*=' mat-column'][_ngcontent-c9]
```

This selector affects every 'td' element in your table that contains a class that starts with ' mat-column' and is combined with another attribute that is a target and starts with '_ngcontent-c9'.

Have you tried the recursive approach like this?

```
td[class*=' mat-column'] *
{
  ...
}
```

This way you can avoid the target attribute entirely that is probably dynamically generated by Angular.

**EDIT:**

I'd also suggest that you avoid using **!important** in your css. I don't find it as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Styles that you define in a component's stylesheet are limited to the scope of that component, meaning that class selectors defined in app.component.css won't affect the style of other components. That's by design to avoid one component conflicting with another component by accidentally changing it's appearance due to same class names being used.

See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope

Angular does this by magically adding some prefixes to the class names.
For your code to work you should either **move the block**

```
.mat-column-owner{
  width:50% !important;
  min-width: 50% !important;
  max-width: 50% !important;
}
```

**to the styles.css file** **or change the selector to** `::ng-deep .mat-column-owner`.

`::ng-deep` is depracted though and will be removed in some future version of angular.